# Can we transfer Magento Enterprise license to another company?

Tags: magento-enterprise

We have signed a three-year contract with Magento Enterprise edition. At the end of the first year, we had stopped operating the Magento website. Can we transfer the remaining Magento Enterprise license (Magento Commerce - M2 ) to another company?

Answer (score 0):

According magento the enterprise license is none transferable, if you got to http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/magento_enterprise_eula.pdf it should be covered within this document